# IE 8 problems: unrecognized expression: first-of-type

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

When I load page, in IE 8 read this error:

> Agente utente: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1;
>   Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E) Timestamp: Fri,
>   27 Apr 2012 18:38:27 UTC
>
> Messaggio: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: first-of-type Linea:
>   3 Carattere: 14659 Codice: 0 URI:
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

In Firefox, Chrome and other thats ok!

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: no please edit your post and paste the code here.

Comment: mmmmmm...i found: $j("#mod_home div p:first-of-type").hide();$j("#mod_home div p:last-of-type").hide(); If I raise these lines the error does not do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:first-of-type` is not a jQuery selector. `:first-of-type` only works in browsers which natively support this selector.

For other browsers, extend the selector set (`$.expr[':']`). Have a look at [this project](https://github.com/keithclark/JQuery-Extended-Selectors). [jquery-extra-selectors.js](https://github.com/keithclark/JQuery-Extended-Selectors/blob/master/jquery-extra-selectors.js) adds support for several pseudo-class selectors.

Comment: Cross browser support for `:first-of-type` and other [CSS3 selectors were added in jQuery 1.9](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/15/jquery-1-9-final-jquery-2-0-beta-migrate-final-released/) (even for IE6)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fetch only the first element inside container then instead of `:first-of-type` you can use `:first-child` selector which is supported even in **IE8**.